# Need Firefox plug-in to show POSTed variables

Tags: firefox

I need to find out what variables and values are being POSTed to a script that I'm debugging. It's doing something strange to them, and it needs to start a session so I can't ouput them right at the beginning. I'm hoping to find a plug-in for Firefox that will show me what they are directly from the browser. Does anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It's awesome.

The Net panel shows you what's going on over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)

Let's you see every request, edit it and replay it. Excelent plugin and easy to use...

Answer (score 0):

Firebug does that perfectly :)

1. install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
2. open the [network](http://getfirebug.com/network) tab

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) has such a plugin and it is also just a good HTTP debugger in general

Answer (score 0):

[LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) is an oldie but a goodie